# tccd stuck and taking up lots of cpu

Tags: macos

Often when I am using XCode (and sometimes other apps) the tccd process will take up lots of CPU or just get stuck. I find myself more and more having to kill that process (now it happens multiple times a day). It always seems to immediately re-start the process as soon as it is killed.

I am wondering if there is a way to fix it so that it does not break all the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this blog post titled: [Fix TCCD process consuming high CPU usage when run Xcode](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/25164713).

*excerpt*

> Using Xcode 8 is really a frustrating experience. When compile swift source files or write code in Sierra(the latest macOS), Xcode frequently freeze. It's nuking productivity. After a long time of searching, I found this is caused by a process named tccd which take up to 70% of CPU usage. What is tccd? It seems to be a access controller that manage the permission to user's contacts. So the solution is quite easy, go to
>
> System Preferences → Security & Privacy → Privacy → Contacts
>
> uncheck Xcode and restart it. Then, it works again.

So it would seem, simply disabling contacts will disable `tccd` thereby dropping the high CPU load.

Comment: This is a lot bigger of an issue on Mojave and seems to be comprehensive vs limited to Contacts now. There seems to be a bug in what Apple has done since perhaps 10.14.2...

Comment: I just had a similar issue with Qt Creator. Every time application is built and run, the system freezes for around 5 to 10 seconds. Removing Qt Creator permission in Accessibility fixes the issue.